# Spring boot Rest service app issues with routing logic to mongo db

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have to create api using spring boot application where the routing logic using apache camel and api should save to Mongo db please help if anyone has created such application.

Comment: Please post any reference example links.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rest component of apache camel

here is a sample [app](https://github.com/techguy-bhushan/Springboot-ApacheCamel-Rest) using apache camel and springboot

```
 rest("/users").description("User REST service")
                .consumes("application/json")
                .produces("application/json")

                .get().description("Find all users").outType(User[].class)
                .responseMessage().code(200).message("All users successfully returned").endResponseMessage()
                .route()
                .to("bean:userService?method=findUsers")
                .endRest()
```

in above camel example, i am creating a rest api for users, which will return list of user.